# What causes this when weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

What causes this? If I use some weight paint tools, it seems like something weird is happening. Areas with no influence are effected 100% for some reason?

Comment: When you "un-paint" a vertex group (paint with a negative value), the influence that the bone corresponding to that region had over it is gone. The vertices in that region are returning to their rest pose.

Comment: I'm referring to the parts that stick out near the end. Even though they have 0% influence, they stick out 100%.

Comment: My guess is that you have weights on some group that are barely perceptible; try un-painting the ones you don't want to have influence again. Turn off "Front Face Only" in the Tools setting under Advanced. This has been my trouble previously.

Comment: But if it was a group, I don't think I would would be able to get rid of it they way I do by the end in in the gif. I wouldnt be able to erase it with that bone selected.

Comment: Since you are (presumably) painting in the gif, I think you are just missing vertices. If what I suggested didn't help, you need to provide more info.

Comment: It's not that. I think the problem was that the space didn't belong to any other bone groups. I added those verts to a nearby bone group and it seems to have fixed it when removing influence.